# How to print using `lp` when I know the printer's IP but not name?

Tags: cups

Our printers have static IPs associated with them. How can I use CUPS and `lp` command to print a file given that I want to specify printer by his local IP, rather than the name? For instance:

`lp -d 192.168.1.104 file.pdf` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *install* a printqueue in CUPS first, and let this printqueue target the print device at address 192.168.1.104.

If the print device is a relative recent one, it will support IPP (*Internet Printing Protocol*) and you may not even need a model specific driver for it, but have CUPS automatically figure out which job options the device supports. This requires a recent version of CUPS.

1. See if the device supports IPP:

   ```
   ippfind [ENTER]
   ```

   You will get a list of all IPP supporting print devices (or CUPS print queues) on your local network, with their IPP *'device URIs* exposed.
2. Now install that print queue to your system, using the device URI listed above for the printer:

   ```
   sudo lpadmin -p printername -v <device-URI> -E -m everywhere
   ```

   The `-m everywhere` parameter will cause CUPS to seek an IPP connection to the device's URI and request a `Get-Printer-Attributes` IPP query. If the printer provides a specific enough answer, CUPS will auto-generate a PPD (*PostScript Printer Description*) and set up a print queue.

---

If above procedure does not work, you can try to use the CUPS web interface: point your browser to http://localhost:631/admin and click "Add printer" and follow instructions there. If this doesn't work, please come back and give more details (see also below).

---

If your printer is a more ancient one, or your CUPS is not modern enough and all of the above does not work, then please add more details to your question: (1) Vendor and exact model name of your device. (2) Version of your CUPS software package.

Comment: The `-m everywhere` option does not work on my system, it says : `lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file.` Under which condition(s) may it work ?

Comment: @SebMa:  (1) `ippfind` needs to return at least one URI for an IPP printer.   (2) Your CUPS version needs to be 2.2.0 or later.  *(Support for the `-m everywhere` parameter providing the generic IPP Everywhere PPD was added in September 2016, I believe.)*